# pyparsing exception explaination: need more precise information on error location

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyparsing

Here is a piece of code which is producing an exception:

```
from pyparsing import *

strg = 'ab3jh-lokdk-12345-lopf9$ab3jh-lokdk-12345-lopfr'
# strg = 'ab3jh-lokdk-12345-lopf9$ab3jh-lokdk-12345-lopf9'

D = Suppress('-')
TYPE_1 = Regex('\w{2}\d\w{2}').setName('tp1')
TYPE_2 = Regex('\w{5}').setName('tp2')
TYPE_3 = Regex('\d{5}').setName('tp3')
TYPE_4 = Regex('\w{4}\d').setName('tp4')

ELM = Group(TYPE_1 + D + TYPE_2 + D + TYPE_3 + D + TYPE_4).setName('elm')

ALL = ELM + (Literal('$')+ELM)[...]

try:
    result = ALL.parseString(strg,parseAll=True)
except ParseException as parse_err:
    print(parse_err.explain())
```

The printed exception explanation is the following:

```
ab3jh-lokdk-12345-lopf9$ab3jh-lokdk-12345-lopfr
                       ^
ParseException: Expected end of text, found '$'  (at char 23), (line:1, col:24)
pyparsing.core.StringEnd - StringEnd
```

As one can see the error is shown to be on the dollar sign when it is actually on the last character. Is there a way to have `pyparsing` indicating where the error actually is (meaning on the last character of the second group)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, pyparsing has a way of bubbling up exceptions a little too far some times. You can override this by using "-" operator instead of "+" as a way of saying "if there is a parse mismatch after here, don't back up and try something else". It raises a `ParseSyntaxException` instead of `ParseException`, so to catch them, you need to do except `ParseBaseException`.

In your parser, try replacing `ELM` with:

```
ELM = Group(TYPE_1 + D - TYPE_2 + D + TYPE_3 + D + TYPE_4).setName('elm')
```

It's basically saying "once you see `TYPE_1` and "-", there better be a valid `ELM` afterward, and if not, it's a syntax error." Don't go overboard though and just replace every "+" with "-" - just do it in those places where you want the parser to commit to parsing the rest of that expression or just give up on an exception.

Comment: So If I use it too much, I might not have an exception produced? Is there any other way that can create less problems?

I thought first that the `depth` parameter of the `exception.explain()` was supposed to act as an error location precision, but changing the value was not changing the parsing error text.

Comment: It's not that you won't get an exception, it's that your parser will raise an exception that will prevent other alternatives from being tried. So if you put the "-" in a place where there aren't any other possible alternative matches, then the "-" will keep the exception local to the specific parser mismatch, and give a specific error message.

Comment: OK. From my point of you view, that effect doesn't look bad. Would you have an example where this "adverse effect" could become an actual problem?